# Google Analytics causing website to duplicate POSTs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We've noticed a very strange behavior change on our website (asp.net MVC) starting early morning (GMT) on the 12'th of January this year (2018).

Http POSTs from the site started firing twice (unconfirmed, but we suspect sometimes more than twice), and scouring high and low we couldn't find that we'd changed anything.

One of the few things we dynamically load is Google Analytics (specifically Google Tag Manager), and in the course of trial-and-error we tried disabling everything external (which made the phenomenon disappear) and then re-enabling them one-by-one, once we came to re-enabling GA the problem re-appeared.
We also tried removing everything except GA and the problem persisted.

When searching we can't find that anything has been updated in GA, so it's very unclear why it suddenly started, and we have also been unable to find anyone else reporting the same problem (either historically or presently).

Our current best guess is that one of GA's dependencies have updated, and either it contains a bug, or it's exposing an already existing fault in our code.

Has anyone else noticed the same problem? Anyone find something in their code that caused the strange behavior of GA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it was caused by two erroneously set up triggers.

Both triggers were form submit type, and both had double activators, one "Activate trigger when all conditions are met" and one "Activate trigger on specific forms".

The problem was that both "all conditions" activators were set to "url matches regular expression .*", where as the second activator for both targeted a correct Form Path for each respectively.

Whoever set it up must have assumed that Google Tag Manager was using a logical "and" between the two activators (not an unrealistic assumption), but based on my testing at least it seems that the trigger activates on either activator matching.

I couldn't see any reason for the first regex match towards ".*", so the fix was to simply supply a unique url expression for each trigger.

No explanation yet as to why it suddenly became a problem, because the configuration has been wrong for a couple of months at least.

P.S. For whatever reason our GTM is not in English, so take my quoted names on fields/etc with a grain of salt as they are translated.

**Update**
The website uses ajax to post the forms, the combination of that and the "Await tags" flag on the triggers are looking as likely sources of why the combined conditions were not acting as expected.
Which means a non-announced performance-update to GTM regarding "Await tags" could have been the catalyst which caused the problem to start occuring with alarming frequency.

Comment: This appears to have been a bug in GTM that was fixed the day after you posted this answer: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/forum/AAAAnP_FwdIQVb2sNyvp5k/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Ftag-manager%2FQVb2sNyvp5k%3Bcontext-place%3Dforum%2Ftag-manager